# pytest make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names -- can't import

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

I have this file structure.

[image]

When ı wrote pytest in my terminal.

ı have this issue !

[image]

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'money_transactions_test'
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
```

Why its can't import money_transactions_test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sharing objects within your tests the easiest thing would be to make use of `conftest.py`

However if you must import, since your test files are in the same package directory I recommend specifying a relative import. ie:

```
from .money_transactions_test import acc_numbers_list
```

Comment: @selman, Which of these two approaches worked for you?